# Typescript React Dispatch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dispatch

```
// MyComponent property
setSelected: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>> | Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[]>>

// App.tsx
const [selected, setSelected] = useState<string[]>(['x'])

<MyComponent setSelected={setSelected} />

// MyComponent
setSelected(['x'])
// type error: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string> & SetStateAction<string[]>
```

I have a setSelected function. It will take string or string list and save it. But both of them give type error. What is the reason?

Also '|' as it appears in the error message indicates the '&' symbol as a symbol. I couldn't understand that either.

Another Type:

```
// MyComponent property
setSelected: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | string[]>>

// App.tsx
const [selected, setSelected] = useState<string[]>(['x'])

<MyComponent setSelected={setSelected} />
// type error: Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | string[]>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a union of functions, typescript resolves the argument as the intersection of of the function arguments.

For example `(arg:string)=>{} | (arg:number)=>{}` will be considered as `(arg:string & number)=>{}`.

React dispatch is defined as `type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;` so it is a function.

SetStateAction is also possible a function, you can have callback version of setState.

So rather than

```
setSelected: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>> | Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[]>>
```

you can use

```
setSelected: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string|string[]>>
```

So the union is applied to the generic which represents the arguments expected by setState.

Comment: When I use it this way, the type error for setSelected is removed. But in the part where I send setSelected as a prop, "Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | string[]>>" error occurs. Instead of setting the type of state I'm creating to string or string[], <string | string[]> then that error goes away and there is no error. This totally didn't fit me. Because I know the type of state I created.

Comment: can you share a bit more of the code please, the types for the props etc.. that expect the dispatch to be passed.

Comment: I wrote in more detail.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the whole picture but it seems that the  App.tsx is rendering the component and passing it the `setSelected` function from `setState` which is defined as accepting only `string[]` values which gives the error. If the component calls App setState with either string or string[] it should also accept it. can make it `useState<string[]|string>(['x'])`

Comment: Yes, when you do as you say, it accepts and there is no mistake. But since we know the contents of the state (for example, 'x' is string, ['x'] is string[]), I didn't find it right to write both together(string | string[]). I don't know, maybe that's the way it should be and the only solution.

Comment: Yea, we know that in this particular situation but the type is defined to allow both `string` and `string[]`. When you pass `setSelected` from app you're letting the component call the parent's `setState` but the signature provided to the child prop allows for more possibilities than the parent `setState` allows. So you can either narrow those or should probably be able to use generics in this case where the generic extends `string|string[]` if you need that flexibility in the component.